# React | useState from another useState, changes are not propagated, how could I refactor it?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, state, react-hooks

Having a state that changes after a while (after fetching content), if I want to construct a variable and build a new state from that, when the first state changes it is not propagated to the second state

How can I solve this? I wouldn't like to merge the 2 states into one since this would mix components that do different things

If you have time you can take a look at the codesandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-sun-mx428?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

And I paste here the code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const wait = ms => new Promise((r, j) => setTimeout(r, ms));

const test2 = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("hi");

  useEffect(() => {
    const testf = async stillMounted => {
      await wait(1000);
      setTest("bye");
    };

    const stillMounted = { value: true };
    testf(stillMounted);
    return () => {
      stillMounted.value = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return test;
};

export default function App() {
  const here = test2();
  const stru = [{ id: "whatever", content: here }];
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(stru);

  console.log(stru);
  console.log(elements);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>stru: {stru[0].content}</h1>
      <h2>elements: {elements[0].content}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to use useEffect pass "here" in the dependecy array then setElements(true)

Comment: You mean like this https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-khorana-w32cr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark BUT in my real code this ends into an infinite loop (not in the sandbox) ...

Comment: i meant here not true, like the guy bellow answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an effect that runs when the `here` variable changes. Add something like this to your `App` component.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // This runs when 'here' changes and then updates your other state
  setElements([{ id: "whatever", content: here }])
}, [here]) // This makes this effect dependent on the 'here' variable
```

Comment: Yes, that's what @gaditzkhori has said in the comments, but I end up in an infinite rerendering of the component. At the end I've solved it by moving part of the code to the parent component to avoid the infinite loop, and effectively run a `useEffect` with `[here]` to re-set the state variable